# Symfony Security: logged in but not granted since update to 5.0

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I have a website working perfectly with Symfony 4.3 with security active and different roles for different users. Everything works perfectly.

Today I decide to upgrade website to Symfony 4.4 then 5.0 then 5.1.

Since 5.0, security hangs: I'm correctly logged in, but all tests (is_granted from twig for example) do not work anymore, like if default voter return false. Roles are correctly reads from DB (checked with a dump).

I think it can comes from a config file but can't figure which one...

BTW: I follow explanations from [SymfonyCasts](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony5-upgrade)

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I've read that symfony completely removed is_granted in the new version as it was deprecated. They introduced new authentication system which will be used in 6.0 https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/experimental_authenticators.html#passport-badges

Comment: Can you show some example? What was deprecated was [passing an array](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/33584) of attributes to be checked. You could install the profiler and check the 'Security' tab to see what voters are being called and what strategy it's applying.